# how to make my angular library installs it's dependencies when using it?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library

now I've made an angular library that depends on ngx bootstrap and others
I don't want the library consumer to install all the dependencies first, but just install my library and that's it
so I wonder if that is possible to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what npm already does, unless you listed it as a peer dependency, then the user would have to install it on his own.